# Calculate and minimize row size to get around effective MySQL column limit

Tags: mysql

I've read the [more nuanced responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473996/mysql-how-many-columns-is-too-many) to the question of how many columns is too many and would like to ask a follow up.

I inherited a pretty messy project (a survey framework), but one could argue that the DB design is actually properly normalized, i.e. a person really has as many attributes as there are questions.
I wouldn't defend that notion in a debate, but the more pressing point is that I have very limited time, I'm trying to help users of this framework out and the quickest fix I can think of right now is reducing the row size. I doubt I have the skill to change the DB model in the time I have.

The column number now is 4661, but they can hopefully reduce it to at least 3244, probably less (by reducing the actual number of questions).
The hard column limit is 4096, but right now I don't even succeed in adding 2500 columns, presumably because of the row size limit which is 65,535 bytes.

However, when I calculate my row size I end up with a much lower value, because nearly all columns are TINYINTs (survey responses ranging from 1-12).
It doesn't even work with 2000 TINYINTs ([an example query that fails](https://gist.github.com/3799625)).

Using the [formula given in the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-count-limit.html) I get 4996 bytes or less.

```
column.lengths = tinyints * 1
null.columns = length(all.columns)
variable.lengths.columns = 0
(row.length = 1+
    (column.lengths)+ 
    (null.columns + 7)/8+ 
    (variable.lengths.columns)
)
## 4996
```

What did I misunderstand in that row length calculation?

Comment: Your columns are `question_1`, `question_2` ... or something like this? Extract these columns in other table `questions` and link it with M:M relation with your `person` table. In `MySQL` you can link this tables with third table `person_question_link` ( `link_id`, `person_id`, `question_id` )

Comment: @dokt Thank you, but that's what I don't have time for, I'm afraid. I would love to do this properly, but I'm looking for a quick fix. I also would like to understand why I'm exceeding the row size/column number limit.

Comment: I'd hurt almost anybody to avoid doing it, but one "fix" would be a multi value column.

Comment: @Tony Survey answers can potentially be added and retrieved one-by-one, so not necessarily a quick fix. The point is also that I didn't write the whole framework and it's messy, there's lots of undocumented implications if I change its "principles". Somebody did a 2000-column survey with this framework before and it performed okay after I played with the indices, I just don't get how I ran into the row size limit now.

Comment: Getting out one by one isn't a problem, given the code is reasonable. i.e there's a GetAnswer Method. Mind you given the table design, I suspect that reasonable might not be an entirely accurate description of the corresponding code. :(

Comment: @Tony It makes me cry sometimes ;-). We'll split it into two surveys now, I hope that decision is wise given the time constraint.

Answer (score 1):

I overlooked this [paragraph](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-count-limit.html)

> Thus, using long column names can reduce the maximum number of
>   columns, as can the inclusion of ENUM or SET columns, or use of column
>   or table comments.

I had long column names, replacing them with sequential numbers allowed me to have more columns (ca. 2693), I'll have to see if the increase is sufficient. I don't know how they're saved, presumably as strings, so maybe I can reduce them even further using letters.