# Handling user rows in SQL with hundreds of boolean values

Tags: mysql, database-schema

I'm working on a fansite about collectible figures, and I want to build a checklist that can help my users track what they do and don't have. As of the current design I have in mind, I'd basically have a boolean for each figure - 1 for 'Have it' and 0 otherwise. Currently there are about 250 figures to account for, so I'd have that many columns and each would hold a boolean value, and then in the future I would tack on more columns as more figures are introduced. My gut tells me, however, that having several hundred columns is poor form.

As a way of cleaning things up, I though about converting the whole thing into one long hex string (so 4 bits worth of booleans per character, or about 75 characters for the current length of the entire list), and then just encoding/decoding it as necessary. While that'd definitely make my rows a lot shorter, it would prevent me from doing things like searching the database for users that have X figurine, in case that's something I would eventually want to do.

Taking all this into account, I have a few questions:

1. Would having tons of columns of booleans like this be a cardinal sin? Would the performance impact be very significant, taking into account that the columns are basically holding the smallest possible data type?
2. Is there another better way of saving such long lists of booleans in a database that hasn't occurred to me?
3. If I wanted to, instead of booleans, have a number that can represent a few different states (i.e., 'Have', 'Don't Have', and 'Want') to give the checklist more functionality, how might that affect the way I handle this problem?

Comment: I'm going to let more experienced people answer points 1 and 2.  As for point 3, you could use the ENUM type.  In terms of efficiency, an ENUM requires less data to be stored than an INT.  Also, this is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473996/mysql-how-many-columns-is-too-many

Comment: I wasn't familiar with the ENUM data type before, but this looks really useful. Definitely a better option than saving the state as an int and then interpreting what that value means at runtime. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. Number of Columns

Having the number and type of columns you mentioned probably won't get you into much trouble considering modern database systems. As David pointed out, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473996/mysql-how-many-columns-is-too-many) might provide some insight on that. However, handling all these columns in your code will make it hard to maintain.

#### 2. Another Way

Instead of using a single table, you could split your data across three tables. One table lists the figures, another one the users, and a third the inventory entries.

figures table:

```
id | figure_name
```

users table:

```
id | user_name
```

inventory table:

```
id | user_id | figure_id | state
```

You can tell mysql to link the tables by using `FOREIGN KEY` and query the combined results using `JOIN`.

The benefit of this structure is, that you have more flexibility. Here are a few examples:

- easily only query for a certain figure
- add additional information about users and figures
- save the time at which a figure was acquired in inventory

#### 3. Additional States

Using the approach described in the section above, you can easily modify the `state` column of the `inventory` table. Instead of having a `BOOL`, you could use an `ENUM` or even `VARCHAR`. In the latter case, however, you could add another table `states` which maps `id` to `state_name`.

Comment: Another benefit of splitting the tables is the ability to store other information about the users and the figures (such as images, cost, user addresses, avatars, etc) that has nothing to do with whether or not the figure is owned by a user.

Comment: I definitely had not considering making a table for individual figure entries, and I think that might be a good way to go. As far as I can tell, going this route would take about the same amount of queries to retrieve collection info compared to having a bunch of boolean columns in the user table. Thanks for your insight guys!