# MySQL - At what point should more than one table be used?

Tags: mysql

Edit for future viewers: Aside from the accepted answer which helped me I found some really good info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473996/mysql-how-many-columns-is-too-many) .

I've got a database with a single table for displaying inventory on a website (RVs). It stores the typical info: year, make, model, etc. I originally made it with 6 extra columns for storing "special features", but I don't like having such a hard limit on what options can be listed. Since I've never messed with more than a single table my gut instinct was to just add 24 or so more columns to cover everything, but something in my head told me that there might be a better way. So when do I decide N columns is too many? The data in these columns will commonly *not* be unique.

(Sorry for crappy diagram)

Current table design:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | year | make | model | price | ft_1 | ft_2 | ft_3 | ft_4 | ft_5 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|    |      |      |       |       |      |      |      |      |      |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Possible better design:

```
table #1
------------------------------------
| id | year | make | model | price |
------------------------------------
|    |      |      |       |       |
------------------------------------

table #2
---------------------------------------------
| unique_id(?) |     feature     | unit_ref |
---------------------------------------------
|       0      | "Diesel Pusher" |  2,6,14  |
---------------------------------------------
```

I feel like a bonus of the second table might be that I could more easily propagate a dropdown containing all the previously entered features to speed up adding new units to inventory.

Is this the right way to go about it, or should I just add more columns and be content?

Thanks.

Comment: What does the column `unit_ref` in table #2 represent?

Comment: It was my attempt to reconcile how I would store which "features" are assigned to which unit by id(s). It looks like that's where the third table comes into play. Still having a hard time wrapping my head around the layout though.

Comment: Ah. So probably not required with the new layout then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Believe it or not, your best option would likely be to add a *third* table.

Since each record in your **rvs** table can be linked to multiple rows in the **features** table, and each **feature** can correspond to multiple **rvs**, you have a many-to-many relationship which is inherently difficult to maintain in a relational dbms. By adding a third "intersection" table you convert it to a one-to-many-to-one relationship which can be enforced declaratively by the dbms.

Your table structure would then become something like

```
rvs
------------------------------------
| id | year | make | model | price |
------------------------------------
|    |      |      |       |       |
------------------------------------

features
--------------------------
| id   |     feature     |
--------------------------
| 1192 | "Diesel Pusher" |
--------------------------

rv_features
----------------------
| rv_id | feature_id |
----------------------
|       |            |
----------------------
```

How do you make use of this? Suppose you want to record the fact that the 2016 Travelmore CampMaster has a 25kW diesel generator. You would first add a record to `rvs` like

```
--------------------------------------------------
| id   | year | make       | model      | price  |
--------------------------------------------------
| 0231 | 2016 | Travelmore | CampMaster | 750000 |
| 2101 | 2016 | Travelmore | Domestant  | 650000 |
--------------------------------------------------
```

(Note the value in the `id` column is entirely arbitrary; its sole purpose is to serve as the **primary key** which uniquely identifies the record. It can encode meaningful information, but it must be something that *will not change* throughout the life of the record it identifies.)

You then add (or already have) the generator in the `features` table:

```
--------------------------------
| id   |     feature           |
--------------------------------
| 1192 | Diesel Pusher 450hp   |
| 3209 | diesel generator 25kW |
--------------------------------
```

Finally, you associate the rv to the feature with a record in `rv_features`:

```
----------------------
| rv_id | feature_id |
----------------------
| 0231  | 3209       |
| 0231  | 1192       |
| 2101  | 3209       |
----------------------
```

(I've added a few other records to each table for context.)

Now, to retrieve the features of the 2016 CampMaster, you use the following SQL query:

```
SELECT r.year, r.make, r.model, f.feature
  FROM rvs r, features f, rv_features rf
  WHERE r.id = rf.rv_id
    AND rv.feature_id = f.id
    AND r.id = '2031';
```

to get

```
----------------------------------------------------------
| year | make       | model      | feature               |
----------------------------------------------------------
| 2016 | Travelmore | CampMaster | diesel generator 25kW |
| 2016 | Travelmore | CampMaster | Diesel Pusher 450hp   |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

To see the rvs with a 25kW generator, change the query to

```
SELECT r.year, r.make, r.model, f.feature
  FROM rvs r, features f, rv_features rf
  WHERE r.id = rf.rv_id
    AND rv.feature_id = f.id
    AND f.id = '3209';
```

Sherantha's link to [A Quick-Start Tutorial on Relational Database Design](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/relational_database_design.html) actually looks like a good intro to table design and normalization; you might find it useful.

Comment: I've come across that layout a few times looking around on SO for an answer, but all the answers seem to be geared towards people who know exactly what to do with that information. Any chance you have a link to something that breaks it down a little?

Comment: Not 100% sure what 'unit_ref' represents, but generally we do not want to keep numerous values in the same field.  It may in fact be necessary to add another table to store these values as well, no?

Comment: Most of my library is in dead-tree format, but I'll have a look around and see what I can find. Meanwhile I've expanded on my answer above with an example, and will be happy to answer any questions you have.

Comment: That edit helped a lot. I suppose the main problem is just my lack of experience with database design. I do appreciate the time you've spent on it and I think with that I can work my way through now.

Answer (score 0):

There is a thing calles "third normal form" it says that everything without the unique ids shuld be unique. This means you need to make a table for year, a table for make a table for models etc and a table where you can combine all these ids to one connected dataset.
But this is not always practical, io think the best way to take this is something in between, like tables for entrys that repeat very often, but there dont need to be an extra table for price with unique ids, that would be overkill i think.

Comment: Is that generally considered best practice then? Because like you say, none of my data is necessarily unique and repeat somewhat often. Aside from that should I be considering the number of columns a single table contains?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better for you to be more familiar with relational database design. [This](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/relational_database_design.html) is a short but great article I have found earlier.

Answer (score 0):

**Based upon your scenario, if you believe no. of features columns remain same then no need for second table.** And in case if there any possibility that features can be increased at any time in future then you should break up your table into two. (RVS & Features). Then create a third table that identify RVS & features as it seems there is many-to-many relationship. So I suggest you to use three tables.