# Is ~44 columns too much for a model? Does it make sense to break a one-to-one relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, database-design, database-schema

I am interested in what the best practice is for a model that has a lot of data attached to it. Most of my app revolve around one model (SKU), and it seems to have more and more things associated with it.

For example, my SKU model has multiple prices, dimensions, weight, recommended prices for multiple price levels, title, description, shelf life, etc. Would it make sense to break all the pricing info to another table? Or break up the SKU into different uses of the SKU and associate them? For example, WebSKU, StockSKU, etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473996/mysql-how-many-columns-is-too-many

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As everyone else said, the design of a database should respond to the logic behind it. Why? Mainly, because it will be easier to maintain and understand.

I was also going to drive attention to normalization rules, as @sawa did.

Generally, is a good approach to normalize your database, as it provides several advantages. You should read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) wikipedia link (at least as a starting point).

Following normal rules will help you to design your database taking into account the logic behind your data.

But [denormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) also has it's advantages. The first (always considered) being optimizing read performance. This basically means having data on one table that you would have had in different tables when following normal rules, and generally makes sense when that data has *some* logic relation.

You have to aim to achieve a balance depending on the problem you are facing.

On the other side, for the tags on your post I can see you are using ruby on rails, that uses the active record pattern. One consequence of the database model you are presenting, is that you will probably have a domain model just as complex. I mean, very large. I don't know every detail about your project, but I guess that it will quickly grow to be a [god object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object), making your code hard to maintain, extend and understand.

Comment: Good points. It's been a long time since I reviewed the normalization rules. I think based on this I will probably break out the different packaging levels into their own objects.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the answer linked by Tom, if all your attributes really belong to that model there is no reason to break it up.  However, if you have columns like `price1`, `price2`, `price3` or `dimension_x_1`, `dimension_y_1`, `dimension_x_2`, `dimension_y_2`, etc, then it usually means you should be creating another table to contain those.

For example, you could set it up so that you have the following models

```
Sku
has_many :prices
has_many :dimensions

Price
belongs_to :sku

Dimension
belongs_to :sku
```

Comment: I don't have fields that are just numbers after the name, but I do have things like pallet barcode, item barcode, carton barcode, and pallet price, carton price, etc. Does it make sense to break those out? The pallet has a bar code and a price and the carton has a bar code and a price, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Database should be designed not according to how many columns it has, but according to logic, particularly following [Codd's normal forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). If there is systematic redundancy in your database, then that is a sign for splitting it into multiple tables. If not, keep it as is.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is good to design data model, taking into account how DB engine works with files and memory. The first bottleneck of PostgreSQL is file IO. Memory consumption is also an important part. When PostgreSQL reads some table data (FYI: table data is not read at Index-Only-Scans) it reads 8 KB (compile time parameter) pages. More tuples in such a page, - less file IO, less memory consumption, better cache using (more often hits, fast prewarming, etc.), better performance.

So, if one have a really high-loaded project, it can be useful to think about separation of often used data to isolated tables (as a next step - place this tables into a separate tablespace on SDD or powerful RAID).

I.e. there should be some balance between a logic simplicity and performance tweaks.