# How to do many columns in per table?

Tags: php, ajax

I want to do a project using php, ajax and jquery related to personal information. But I have about 80 columns  per table. Is this good or not?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473996/mysql-how-many-columns-is-too-many

Comment: Normalize your tables. Please apply basic three normal forms.1NF,2NF,3NF

Comment: Please, provide more information