# How to extend a User table with new table in laravel to hold more columns (not a pivot table)?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So in laravel I have a User table holding info such as id, home_address, email_address, phone_number, etc.
Users can participate in dinners (activity). If they don't show up to the dinners, admins should be able to ban the user from participating until they are manually unbanned.

The user table is "large enough" that it doesn't make sense to add new columns to the user table, but instead create a new table to keep the information seperate.

In my User migration file I have

```php
Schema::create('dinner_ban', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('id');
    $table->foreign('id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->dateTime('date_ban');
    $table->dateTime('date_unban');
    $table->string('reason')->nullable();
});
```

and in my User Model file I have

```php
public function userBanned() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'dinner_ban');
}
```

NOTE: dinner_ban does not have it's own individual Model Class.

The table is one way. When a user is banned, they are added to the dinner_ban table with today's date, an estimate future date where they would be unbanned (but of course can be before or after this date (in the future it would be automatic), and a reason for the ban (which doesn't need to be added/provided). When they are unbanned, they are removed from the table. No tracking is done as for how long or how many times someone has been banned. Its a simple check to see the user is banned or not. If they are banned, then they can not participate in dinners.

What I have above, is this a correct way of adding dinner_ban?

In the future there are 3 ways of using it.
If it's the admins, I want to return the whole DB and display the results on the page.
If it's the individual user, I want to check if their id exists in the ban database and return true (with when the ban started, when it ends, and the reason) or false.
And of course admins can edit the individual banned members and edit the reason/estimated unban list.

Comment: What does the number of columns on the table have to do with it not making sense to add another column that seems to be relevant (and a one-to-one?)? You can limit what it is your queries search for and if your tables are keyed and indexed appropriately performance should be fine. You're also introducing a join, which is an additional query and performance hit. Have a read through [this question regarding table limits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1474049/281278)

Comment: Maybe i am missing something but why don't you add a model for UserBanned and make to one to one relation? According to your schema, the userBanned relation is wrong. You need to use join query in your current schema.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to create a custom table like "dinner_ban" to store this kind of information.

It is better to create (if you don not already have) a "user_preferences" table with something like the following structure:

```
 Schema::create('user_preferences', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('id');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->json('value')->nullable();
});
```

and define the relation (and Cast) in "User" Model:

```
public function userPreferences() {
    return $this->hasOne(UserPreferences::class);
}
```

Note: It's better to make "user_id" unique in preferences table and set "value" as json.